# jQuery Date "Invalid Date"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma função de contagem regressiva que funciona regularmente no *Google Chrome*

```
var now = new Date();
var countTo = new Date("9 July 2015 14:30:00:00");
alert(countTo);
$('.timer').countdown(countTo, function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    switch(event.type) {
        case "seconds":
        case "minutes":
        case "hours":
        case "days":
        case "weeks":
        case "daysLeft":
            $this.find('span.'+event.type).html(event.value);
            break;
        case "finished":
            $this.hide();
            break;
    }
});
```

Porém, dei um `alert(countTo);` no Firefox e obtive a mensagem *Invalid Date*. 
Basicamente esse script serve para fazer a comparação com uma data *x* e gerar a contagem regressiva.

Comment: Acho que tem um 00 a mais na data. tente com `new Date("9 July 2015 14:30:00 GMT");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rafael.

Tente usar este formato de data.

```
var countTo = new Date("2015/07/09 10:00:00");
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta retirar os milissegundos que funciona no IE, FF, e CH:

```
var countTo = new Date("9 July 2015 14:30:00");
alert(countTo);
```